# Do reference all public properties in debug methods

Tags: flutter, dart

The latest version of `Flutter` gives me the following link warning saying `Do reference all public properties in debug methods` wherever i have declared public properties. What does this mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: I am facing same issue. for Flutter + Sonar

Answer (score 0):

You have missed any property to describe in your `debugFillProperties()`.You can see [the full documentation here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/diagnostic_describe_all_properties.html)

Comment: even after reading the docs it is not clear. whats the purpose?

Comment: If you could show some of your code.. It would be great